# changing repeater label on treeview selected node change

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a repeater control with item template like this:

```
 <ItemTemplate>
                    <table width="70%">
                        <tr id="rowSIC" runat="server">
                            <td width="10%">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblsSICCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SICCode") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td width="70%">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IndustryName") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td width="10%">
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelect" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("SICCode") %>'
                                    CommandName="MyUpdate">Select</asp:LinkButton>
                            </td>
                            <td width="10%">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ItemTemplate>
```

and itemCommand event where I am changing the repeater row color and saving its id in viewstate like this:

```
Protected Sub Repeater1_ItemCommand(source As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterCommandEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.ItemCommand
        If e.CommandName.Equals("MyUpdate") Then
            Dim MyLabel As Label = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("lblsSICCode"), Label)
            Dim Label1 As Label = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("Label1"), Label)
            Dim rowSIC As HtmlTableRow = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("rowSIC"), HtmlTableRow)

            If MyLabel IsNot Nothing Then
                ' Label1.Text = MyLabel.Text
                rowSIC.BgColor = "#FFDAB9"
                ViewState.Add("selectedItem", MyLabel.Text)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

I have a treeview on this page of which each node has and Id and value. on selected node change event, I want to change the text of repeater selected node. I am writing code like this:

Protected Sub TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TreeView1.SelectedNodeChanged

```
    Dim EmployeeRepeater As Repeater = CType(Me.Form.Controls(1).FindControl("Repeater1"), Repeater)
    Dim EmployeeRepeaterItem As RepeaterItem
    Dim EmployeeName As Label

    For Each EmployeeRepeaterItem In Repeater1.Items

        Dim MyLabel As Label = TryCast(EmployeeRepeaterItem.FindControl("lblsSICCode"), Label)
        EmployeeName = CType(EmployeeRepeaterItem.FindControl("Label1"), Label)

        If ViewState("selectedItem") = TreeView1.SelectedValue Then
            EmployeeName.Text = TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text
        End If


    Next

End Sub
```

But It is not chagging MyLabel text. How to fix it ?

Both treeview and repeater are populated in !Page.Ispostback event

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Comment: If you set a break point on the line     Dim MyLabel As Label = TryCast(EmployeeRepeaterItem.FindControl("lblsSICCode"), Label), is MyLabel null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the method,

TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

You never set the value of MyLabel.

You should have something like MyLabel.Text = "Hello";